# Android volley timeout not properly working

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using android volley and when i make a request i get a timeout error. I increased the timeout using

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                5000, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

The problem to this implementation is i get a result with request.finish: 7123ms. I should have taken a timeoutError. Is something i haven't understand about android timeout? How can i set the timeout to 5000ms precisely?

Edited:
I found at [prasadthangavel.blogspot](http://prasadthangavel.blogspot.gr/2013/12/why-volley-android-has-provided-two.html) that in every retry the request is increasing its time. I thought that this should be my problem, but 
If i edit my request to

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                5000, 0,0));
```

according to android volley default retry policy

```
@Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
        mCurrentRetryCount++;
        mCurrentTimeoutMs += (mCurrentTimeoutMs * mBackoffMultiplier);
        if (!hasAttemptRemaining()) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns true if this policy has attempts remaining, false otherwise.
     */
    protected boolean hasAttemptRemaining() {
        return mCurrentRetryCount <= mMaxNumRetries;
    }`
```

no other retry will be made. But this also didn't solve my problem. I have some requests which are being executed with request.finish 7200ms. Why an exception is not being thrown every time the connection time or readtime is bigger than 5000ms?

Comment: where should i call `setRequestPolicy()?` I am facing similar timeout problem.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same problem. I was thinking maybe RetryPolicy only works for retries and not for the initial request, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Check your code

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

You set timout to 5000ms, and no of retries to DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, whose value is 1, it means. Your request timeout is 5sec for first request and then 5sec for retry request. After two request that means 10 sec in your case. Request timeout will occur.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've set my TIMEOUT_MS to be 1000ms (1 sec) and the MAX_RETRIES to 0. But the initial request is taking 45sec to come back with an error message. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Volley sets default Socket & ConnectionTImeout to 5 secs for all requests.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: So in my example my timeout is 5000 + 5000 = 10000?